# Command in a infinite thinking loop

Tags: discord.js

When I try to run my command, it does as intended but is stuck in a thinking loop when it should send a message. Here is my code and a screenshot of what's happening to the command. The code should be timing out a user for a reason or none, and this is running on a server i have tried running the code on my computer and when i run the command it work's fine. But when i try running it on the server it goes into a loop that the bot is thinking but it does timeout the user.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits } = require('discord.js');
const ms = require('ms')

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('timeout')
    .setDescription('Times out a user for a reason.')
    .addUserOption((option) => 
        option
            .setName('user')
            .setDescription('The user you want to timeout.')
            .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addStringOption((option) => 
    option
        .setName('duration')
        .setDescription('How long you want to timeout the user for.')
        .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addStringOption((option) => 
    option
        .setName('reason')
        .setDescription('The reason you want to timeout the user.')
    ),

    run: async ({ interaction }) => {
        const user = interaction.options.get('user').value
        const reason = interaction.options.get('reason')?.value || 'No reason provided.'
        const duration = interaction.options.get('duration').value

        await interaction.deferReply();

        const targetUser = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(user)

        if (!targetUser) {
            await interaction.editReply("That user doesn't exist in the server.")
            return;
        }

        const msDuration = ms(duration)

        if(isNaN(msDuration)) {
            await interaction.editReply('Please give a valid timeout duration.')
            return;
        }

        if(msDuration < 5000 || msDuration > 2.419e9) {
            await interaction.editReply('Timeout cannot be less than 5 seconds and over 28 days.')
            return;
        }

        const targetUserRolePos = targetUser.roles.highest.position;
        const requestUserRolePos = interaction.member.roles.highest.position;
        const botRolePos = interaction.guild.members.me.roles.highest.position;

        if (targetUserRolePos >= requestUserRolePos) {
            await interaction.editReply('That user has a higher role than you cant time them out.')
            return;
        }

        if (targetUserRolePos >= botRolePos) {
            await interaction.editReply('I cant timeout that user because they have the same or higher role than me.')
            return;
        }

        try {
            const { default: prettyMs } = await import('pretty-ms')

            if (targetUser.isCommunicationDisabled()) {
                await targetUser.timeout(msDuration, reason);
                await interaction.editReply(`${targetUser}'s timeout has been updated to ${prettyMs(msDuration, { verbose: true })}`)
                return;
            }

            await targetUser.timeout(msDuration, reason);
            await interaction.editReply(`${targetUser} was timed out for ${prettyMs(msDuration, { verbose: true })}.\nReason: ${reason}`)
            return;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`There was an error: ${error} Maybe log this in bug tracked?`)
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

[loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yX3Rd.png)